# Ajax is not working.when the servlet gives error it redirects to another page with error message

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

```
<form name="formotp" action="OtpRegistrationSrevlet" method="post" id="formotp">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="otp">Enter OTP</label> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required pattern="\d{6}" name="otp" />
        <button type="submit" id="bttnotp">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ajax Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formotp").on("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#formotp").hide();
            $("#spinregister").show();
            var f = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url : "OtpRegistrationSrevlet",
                type : 'POST',
                data : f,
                success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $("#spinregister").hide();
                    $("#errordivreg").load(location.href + " #errordivreg");
    

                if (data.trim() === 'error') {
                        $("#formotp").show();
                    } else {
                        window.location = "Home.jsp";
                    }
                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#formotp").show();
                    $("#spinregister").hide();
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Inside success it will check if the servlet returned error or not. if it returns error then
it should do accordingly. but instead it is redirecting to another page and printing error there

Servlet code:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
        
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            HttpSession s = request.getSession();
            int otp = (Integer) s.getAttribute("userotp");
            int enteredOtp = Integer.parseInt((request.getParameter("otp").trim()));
            if (otp == enteredOtp) {
                
            } else {

        out.println("error");// error message
        return;
    }
```

}

> i am facing problem here. whenever the otp is incorrect it print error. In ajax its checks if data received is equal to error then it should show form again but instead i am getting this error printed on new blank page

Comment: what does `data` has in it ?

Comment: "error"- the message i am sending from servlet else block.

Comment: did you `alert(data)` and checked if its giving you correct value . ? your code seems ok to me